# Definitions for DNS Server Settings?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am looking at master DNS settings on my Enom domain.  I'm wondering what the difference is between the following....

```
www
@
*
```

www is a bit obvious, but what about the others?  What is @ if it doesn't apply to email?  At least, the MX records relate to all of the email, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` character is used to denote a [wildcard record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).  A wildcard is basically used to provide an answer for to questions related to records that don't exist in your zone.

The `www` is just a typical name.

The `@` character is a special character that usually as shorthand for the current domain.  So for the zone `example.org` the `@` characters is shorthand for `example.org`.

Also see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your domain record for **nowhere.net** has these two entries:

```
@ IN A  78.90.12.34
* IN CNAME nowhere.net.
```

The @ sign in a record means the domain itself with no host, i.e. **nowhere.net**.  This would allow someone to put http://nowhere.net in their browser and resolve to 78.90.12.34.

The * sign in a record is a wildcard for any hostname.  You could enter www.nowhere.net, ftp.nowhere.net, mail.nowhere.net, yo-mama.nowhere.net, etc. and they would all resolve to the IP specified for the domain.  You wouldn't have to set each one up with a separate record.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, as far as they go, though they don't really explain @ fully.

In DNS parlance, "@" is short for the origin.  **Typically** this is the same as the zone name because it is inherited from the zone name unless otherwise specified, but it **can** be changed within a zone file by using the $ORIGIN directive.

Finally, as long as we are on the subject of the "@" character, it should not occur in e-mail addresses when they are called for in zone files (for example, the zone administrator address in the SOA record.)  When an e-mail address is written in an SOA record, the "@" character is replaced by a period, i.e. "admin@example.net" is written "admin.example.net" in an SOA record.